# Nested menu (sub-menu)

Tags: reactjs, redux, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I'm trying to implement Sub-menu (nested menu).

It's worth to mention that I'm using hydra component and don't have previous experience with redux (started learning it a few days ago because of this specific problem).

I've followed the example provided on material-ui  for nested list https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/#nested-list. And tutorial from 
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-menu for custom menu implementation.

So I have a few questions.

1) Can I have stateful component (MyMenu) just for handling toggling of menu items?

An example is not related to react-admin but its just example what I mean.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addArticle } from "../actions/index";
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addArticle: article => dispatch(addArticle(article))
  };
};
class ConnectedForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { title } = this.state;
    const id = uuidv1();
    this.props.addArticle({ title, id });
    this.setState({ title: "" });
  }
  render() {
    const { title } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="title"
            value={title}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">
          SAVE
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const Form = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedForm);
export default Form;
```

2) If not, can I achieve that by declaring a new state in store, for example, open: false, and then using the custom reducer to handle that.

3(bonus). If it's not a problem I would appreciate if someone can put me in the right direction which things to start learning first so I can less painfully manage to solve issues related to this amazing framework :)

Answer (score 12):

The react-admin demo now shows a way to do so in [examples/demo/src/layout/Menu.js](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/925408c86b665fa026c7798b4af10fc70127be86/examples/demo/src/layout/Menu.js):

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';
import LabelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Label';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    translate,
    DashboardMenuItem,
    MenuItemLink,
    Responsive,
} from 'react-admin';

import visitors from '../visitors';
import orders from '../orders';
import invoices from '../invoices';
import products from '../products';
import categories from '../categories';
import reviews from '../reviews';
import SubMenu from './SubMenu';

class Menu extends Component {
    state = {
        menuCatalog: false,
        menuSales: false,
        menuCustomers: false,
    };

    static propTypes = {
        onMenuClick: PropTypes.func,
        logout: PropTypes.object,
    };

    handleToggle = menu => {
        this.setState(state => ({ [menu]: !state[menu] }));
    };

    render() {
        const { onMenuClick, open, logout, translate } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {' '}
                <DashboardMenuItem onClick={onMenuClick} />
                <SubMenu
                    handleToggle={() => this.handleToggle('menuSales')}
                    isOpen={this.state.menuSales}
                    sidebarIsOpen={open}
                    name="pos.menu.sales"
                    icon={<orders.icon />}
                >
                    <MenuItemLink
                        to={`/commands`}
                        primaryText={translate(`resources.commands.name`, {
                            smart_count: 2,
                        })}
                        leftIcon={<orders.icon />}
                        onClick={onMenuClick}
                    />
                    <MenuItemLink
                        to={`/invoices`}
                        primaryText={translate(`resources.invoices.name`, {
                            smart_count: 2,
                        })}
                        leftIcon={<invoices.icon />}
                        onClick={onMenuClick}
                    />
                </SubMenu>
                <SubMenu
                    handleToggle={() => this.handleToggle('menuCatalog')}
                    isOpen={this.state.menuCatalog}
                    sidebarIsOpen={open}
                    name="pos.menu.catalog"
                    icon={<products.icon />}
                >
                    <MenuItemLink
                        to={`/products`}
                        primaryText={translate(`resources.products.name`, {
                            smart_count: 2,
                        })}
                        leftIcon={<products.icon />}
                        onClick={onMenuClick}
                    />
                    <MenuItemLink
                        to={`/categories`}
                        primaryText={translate(`resources.categories.name`, {
                            smart_count: 2,
                        })}
                        leftIcon={<categories.icon />}
                        onClick={onMenuClick}
                    />
                </SubMenu>
                <SubMenu
                    handleToggle={() => this.handleToggle('menuCustomer')}
                    isOpen={this.state.menuCustomer}
                    sidebarIsOpen={open}
                    name="pos.menu.customers"
                    icon={<visitors.icon />}
                >
                    <MenuItemLink
                        to={`/customers`}
                        primaryText={translate(`resources.customers.name`, {
                            smart_count: 2,
                        })}
                        leftIcon={<visitors.icon />}
                        onClick={onMenuClick}
                    />
                    <MenuItemLink
                        to={`/segments`}
                        primaryText={translate(`resources.segments.name`, {
                            smart_count: 2,
                        })}
                        leftIcon={<LabelIcon />}
                        onClick={onMenuClick}
                    />
                </SubMenu>
                <MenuItemLink
                    to={`/reviews`}
                    primaryText={translate(`resources.reviews.name`, {
                        smart_count: 2,
                    })}
                    leftIcon={<reviews.icon />}
                    onClick={onMenuClick}
                />
                <Responsive
                    xsmall={
                        <MenuItemLink
                            to="/configuration"
                            primaryText={translate('pos.configuration')}
                            leftIcon={<SettingsIcon />}
                            onClick={onMenuClick}
                        />
                    }
                    medium={null}
                />
                <Responsive
                    small={logout}
                    medium={null} // Pass null to render nothing on larger devices
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    open: state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen,
    theme: state.theme,
    locale: state.i18n.locale,
});

const enhance = compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        {}
    ),
    translate
);

export default enhance(Menu);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've searched the same question. But couldn't find a nested menu implementation. So I wrote my own. Check the code below;

```
import React, { Component, createElement } from "react";
import {
  Admin,
  Resource,
  Layout,
  MenuItemLink,
  getResources
} from "react-admin";
import jsonServerProvider from "ra-data-json-server";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  Collapse,
  ListItemText,
  ListItemIcon
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { ExpandLess, ExpandMore, StarBorder, LabelIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const menuStyles = theme => ({
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 4
  }
});

class Menu extends Component {
  menuList = [
    { name: "A", label: "Top menu 1", icon: <LabelIcon /> },
    { name: "B", label: "Top menu 2", icon: <LabelIcon /> },
    { name: "c", label: "Top menu 3", icon: <LabelIcon /> }
  ];
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: "A" };
  }
  render() {
    const { resources, onMenuClick, logout } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <List component="nav">
          {this.menuList.map(menu => {
            return (
              <div key={menu.name}>
                <ListItem
                  button
                  onClick={() => this.setState(state => ({ open: menu.name }))}
                >
                  <ListItemIcon>{menu.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText inset primary={menu.label} />
                  {this.state.open == menu.name ? (
                    <ExpandLess />
                  ) : (
                    <ExpandMore />
                  )}
                </ListItem>
                <Collapse
                  in={this.state.open == menu.name}
                  timeout="auto"
                  unmountOnExit
                >
                  <List component="div" disablePadding>
                    {resources
                      .filter(x => x.options.menu == menu.name)
                      .map((resource, i) => (
                        <MenuItemLink
                          key={"m" + i}
                          to={`/${resource.name}`}
                          primaryText={resource.options.label || resource.name}
                          leftIcon={
                            resource.icon
                              ? createElement(resource.icon)
                              : undefined
                          }
                          onClick={onMenuClick}
                          className={this.props.classes.nested}
                        />
                      ))}
                  </List>
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var MenuWithStyles = withStyles(menuStyles)(Menu);

const MyMenu = withRouter(
  connect(state => ({
    resources: getResources(state)
  }))(MenuWithStyles)
);

const MyLayout = props => <Layout {...props} menu={MyMenu} />;

const App = () => (
    <Admin      
      ...
      appLayout={MyLayout}
    >
      <Resource 
        ...
        options={{ label: 'Page 1' menu: "A" }}
      />
      <Resource 
        ...
        options={{ label: 'Page 2' menu: "A" }}
      />
      <Resource 
        ...
        options={{ label: 'Page 3' menu: "B" }}
      />
    </Admin>
  );
```