# Add a top level menu in react-admin

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

How can i a a top level menu in the appbar between the title and the usermenu ?

I tried something like this, but it do not work :

```
const MyAppBar = props => <AppBar {...props} userMenu={<MyUserMenu />} ><MyTopMenu /></AppBar>
```

Comment: What do you mean by top level menu ? A menu like the usermenu inside the appbar?

Comment: A meunu like https://material-ui.com/api/menu/.

Comment: The link you provided shows a material-ui Menu's props, it is not clear what type of menu you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a sub-menu in react-admin, you'll need to create a custom sub-menu component following the  [nested list](https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/#nested-list) technique from material-ui.
You will also need to create and use a custom menu as explained in react-admin's [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-menu).

Comment: Thank you, but its for the sidebar menu. How to put this component in appbar ?

Comment: Well, this is beyond the functionality and design of react-admin, so I guess you could try creating a custom AppBar that embeds one of the menus described in material-ui (https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/) but I am not sure if it would work or how you could go about it.

Answer (score 1):

1. An official way provided from the demo of react-admin: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/layout/Menu.tsx ([related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54639773/2793318))
2. Check this new plugin dedicated for this purpose: [ra-tree-menu](https://github.com/TheMisir/ra-tree-menu)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the `ra-tree-menu` package mentioned above by [kxo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793318/kxo) didn't seem to be working well, I had to resort to develop a new package for this which could solve the use-case and further offer much more ease and flexibility for achieving the purpose.

You can check this out: [ra-treemenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bb-tech/ra-treemenu). A quick example of using it would be something like:

```js
// In App.js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, Layout } from 'react-admin';
/* Import TreeMenu from the package */
import TreeMenu from '@bb-tech/ra-treemenu';
 
const App = () => (
    <Admin layout={(props) => <Layout {...props} menu={TreeMenu} />} >
        {/* Dummy parent resource with isMenuParent options as true */}
        <Resource name="users" options={{ "label": "Users", "isMenuParent": true }} />
        {/* Children menu items under parent */}
        <Resource name="posts" options={{ "label": "Posts", "menuParent": "users" }} />
        <Resource name="comments" options={{ "label": "Comments", "menuParent": "users" }} />
        {/* Dummy parent resource with isMenuParent options as true */}
        <Resource name="groups" options={{ "label": "Groups", "isMenuParent": true }} />
        {/* Children menu items under parent */}
        <Resource name="members" options={{ "label": "Members", "menuParent": "groups" }} />
    </Admin>
);
 
export default App;
```

Comment: Are there any plans of upgrading the package to react-admin 4.x?