# Can we add submenu to Users ,post and dashboard in react-admin ?If yes, how can we add?

Tags: submenu, react-admin

We are facing a problem adding submenu to Users in react-admin.

```
const App = () => (
<Admin loginPage={CustomLoginPage} authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="users" list={UserList} create={UserCreate} edit={UserEdit} show={UserShow} icon={UserIcon} />
    <Resource name="regions" list={RegionList} icon={RegionIcon} />
    <Resource name="hospitals" list={HospitalList} create={HospitalCreate} icon={HospitalIcon} />
</Admin>
```

);

For Users we need submenu in react-admin.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a code example from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54639773/4896467

Check the latest version of react-admin and search for `Menu.js` and `SubMenu.js` under demo example.
They also have sub menus on their demo page.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/